# Parse JSON with NET Framework 3.5. Can't get data from object

Tags: c#, json, .net-3.5

I just can't get key and value for embedded object in json.
I want to get these keys and values like `{ user: 'admin', msg: 'exit' }`.
With this code I get item.Key (that is id in that json) and item.Value (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object])
But I just don't know what to do with this object. How to get data from it?
I get json from server -

```
{
    "365": {
        "user": "admin",
        "msg": "exit"
    },
    "366": {
        "user": "user",
        "msg": "enter"
    },
    "370": {
        "user": "user",
        "msg": "exit"
    },
    "372": {
        "user": "user",
        "msg": "exit"
    },
    "373": {
        "user": "admin",
        "msg": "exit"
    }
}
```

Thank you for any answer.

P.S. 
I don't want to use any external libs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace JSONTestconsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Proxy = null;
            string data = wc.DownloadString("http://temp.net");

            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var obj = ser.DeserializeObject(data) as ICollection;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in obj)
            {
                var id = item.Key;
                Console.WriteLine(id);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not valid json

Comment: Fixed, but still don't know what to do with item.Value object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deserializing to `Object` which wont expose the value properties.  json represents a serializied object, so it is better to deserialize to the same Type:

```
public class UserMsg
{
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
}
```

To use that as the Value target Type:

```
string jstr = ...from whereever
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, UserMsg> myCol = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, UserMsg>>(jstr);

// test result:
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, UserMsg> kvp in myCol)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", kvp.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("  Value: {0}, {1}", kvp.Value.user, kvp.Value.msg);
}
```

Output:

> Key: 365
>     Value: admin, exit
>   Key: 366
>     Value: user, enter
>   (etc)

VS will help make the class: put the valid json on the clipboard; then
 **Edit Menu -> Paste Special -> Paste Json as Class**.

You may have to tweak a few things.  I think it was VS2010 where this feature was added.