# Get all json keys and values in c# (Unity)

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

any way to loop in a `json` file and print all keys and values like a dictionary?

## Example

```
foreach (string item in result.Data.Keys)
   {
      Debug.LogError("KEY:"+item);
      Debug.LogError("Value:" + result.Data[item]);
   }
```

I have tried `JsonUtility` and simple `json`, but i cant print the `KEY value` yet

Any solution? thanks

Comment: {"key1":"value1"} do you want to print the value as "key1", "value1"?

Comment: yes, that is what i want

Comment: You're not get it from item. Seems like your code is correct. if possible update the value of  result.Data.Keys

Comment: Please these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413406/parse-json-with-net-framework-3-5-cant-get-data-from-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859753/what-is-the-simplest-c-sharp-function-to-parse-a-json-string-into-an-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `JsonUtility` class is limited to deserializing into plain classes and structs. Deserialization into dictionaries does not seem to be supported at this time. [LitJSON](https://litjson.net/) is quite a bit more flexible.

Using LitJSON:

```
var deserializedObject = JsonMapper.ToObject(json_text);
foreach(var key in deserializedObject.Keys) 
{
    var value = deserializedObject[key]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using FullSerializer instead for your JSON files which is a bit more powerful than the standard JSON Utility. It is available from https://github.com/jacobdufault/fullserializer.

In this case you can use the `fsData.AsDictionary` to convert it to a regular dictionary.

```
fsData data = fsJsonParser.Parse(serializedString);
// do something with `data.AsDictionary`
```

Then you would iterate over the resulting Dictionary as normal.

Comment: I have removed my answer as it didn't seem relevant to Unity projects.